# Topic: disease prediction using classification algorithm from given data error in code

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, classification

am doing internship in AIML and am getting a few errors in my major project please help me out. i have uploaded the code and errors below.
the versions are up to date.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img,img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,log_loss,accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_path=r"C:\Users\iamak\OneDrive\Documents\Training"
test_path=r"C:\Users\iamak\OneDrive\Documents\Testing"
File=[]
for f in os.listdir(train_path):
      File +=[f]
print(File)
train_data=[]

'''label encoding '''
mapping={'no_tumor':0, 'pituitary_tumor':1, 'meningioma_tumor':2, 'glioma_tumor':3}

count=0

for f in os.listdir(train_path):
         ''' joining path '''
         path=os.path.join(train_path,f)
         for im in os.listdir(path):
             ''' loading an image '''
             img=load_img(os.path.join(path,im),grayscale=False,color_mode='rgb',target_size=(150,150))
             ''' converting an image to array'''
             img = img_to_array(img)
             ''' scaling '''
             img=img / 225.0
             ''' appending image to train_data'''
             train_data.append([img,count])
         count=count+1
         
test_data= []

'''label encoding '''
mapping={'no_tumor':0,'pituitary_tumor':1, 'meningioma_tumor':2, 'glioma_tumor':3}
count=0

for f in os.listdir(test_path):
         ''' joining path '''
         path=os.path.join(test_path,f)
         for im in os.listdir(path):
             ''' loading an image '''
             img=load_img(os.path.join(path,im),grayscale=False,color_mode='rgb',target_size=(150,150))
             ''' converting an image to array'''
             img = img_to_array(img)
             ''' scaling '''
             img=img / 225.0
             ''' appending image to train_data'''
             test_data.append([img,count])
         count=count+1
train_images,train_labels=zip(*train_data)
test_images,test_labels=zip(*test_data)
train_labels=to_categorical(train_labels)
train_images=np.array(train_images)

train_labels=np.array(train_labels)

print(train_images.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)
test_labels=to_categorical(test_labels)
test_images=np.array(test_images)

test_labels=np.array(test_labels)

print(test_images.shape)
print(test_labels.shape)
train_images=train_images.reshape(-1,150,150,3)
test_images=test_images.reshape(-1,150,150,3)
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(train_images,train_labels,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
data_aug=ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True,vertical_flip=True,width_shift_range=0.2,height_shift_range=0.2,shear_range=0.1)
model1=tf.keras.applications.DenseNet201(input_shape=(150,150,3),include_top=False)
model1.trainable=False
inp=model1.input

x=tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(model1.output)

out=tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,activation='softmax')(x)

model=tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp,outputs=out)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(data_aug.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=32),validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=30)
```

im getting the error as:ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 1
----> 1 history=model.fit(data_aug.flow(x_train,y_train,batch_size=32),validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs=30)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71 finally:
72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp_*autograph_generated_filed6nzooty.py:15, in outer_factory..inner_factory..tf__train_function(iterator)
13 try:
14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval* = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16 except:
17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_step
    loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
    return self.compiled_loss(
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
    loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 142, in __call__
    losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 268, in call  **
    return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1984, in categorical_crossentropy
    return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
File "C:\Users\iamak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5559, in categorical_crossentropy
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

ValueError: Shapes (None, None) and (None, None, None, 4) are incompatible
```

please help if you need more code i will provide

Comment: There is an error in your output layer or how you pass the labels. So would you check the shape of your train and validation data, also print the model.summary() to check your layers.